# Scala IDE doesn't show documentation during autocomplete hints

Tags: eclipse, scala, scala-ide

I can't see any documentation when I press "Ctrl + space" to see all the available functions.

For instance, in a Java class I can see the javadoc associated with each method:

[image]

But when I try to view the same information in a Scala worksheet, I can't see anything:

[image]

However, if I make a hover with my mouse over the method once it has been written I can see the documentation:

[image]

This behaviour is very annoying. Does anyone know how to do it in scalaIDE? Do I need to configure anything?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are using a non built-in compiler. In my case I was using as an installed compiler scala-2.12.0-M5.

If that is the case, try using a built-in one.

See also my last comment to the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

The new version should have the scaladoc integration working. Can you check if the Scala->Run Setup Diagonostics window and see if the two JDT options are checked?

[ScalaIDE](http://scala-ide.org/blog/release-notes-4.0.0-RC1.html)

[image]

Comment: I'm using ScalaIDE 4.3 in a Mac computer and without changing anything I can't see that help in a Scala worksheet

Comment: Hmm. Here is the fixed defect : https://scala-ide-portfolio.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000210-scaladoc-integration-with-code-completion/details

Comment: I have the same problem that @jfcorugedo reports. The problem shows up  using Scala IDE 4.4.1 both in Eclipse Mars and Neon and on Windows and OSX. Both JDT options in Scala->Run Setup Diagnostics window are checked.  Any clue?

Comment: i suggest you drop a question here : https://gitter.im/scala-ide/scala-ide

Comment: I found the following issues: 1) Scaladoc is not shown when using non built-in compilers. 2) Javadoc is never shown in a Scala file. 3) Object, as Console or Predef, methods are not shown. 4) Other methods sometimes are shown sometimes not. For instance def ++[B >: A, That](that: GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That is always shown but def ++[B >: A, That](that: TraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That normally is not shown